# What do you call the plastic tube you put in a glass to drink? (image included)

Tags: word-request, image-identification

Would you please tell me what does this called in English?

[image: a glass of orange juice with a straw]

Comment: What do you call it in your language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a **drinking straw** (or simply [**straw**](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/straw)).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drinking_straw):

> A **drinking straw** is a tube for transferring a beverage from its container to the mouth of the drinker. A thin tube of plastic (such as polypropylene and polystyrene) or other material, straight or with an angle-adjustable bellows segment, it is used by being held with one end in the mouth and another end in the drink. Muscular action (a combination of the muscles of the tongue and cheeks) reduces air pressure in the mouth and above the liquid in the straw, whereupon atmospheric pressure forces the beverage through the straw. [...] A **bendable straw** or "bendy straw" (known in the industry as an "articulated straw") has a concertina-type hinge near the top for convenience. This variation was invented by Joseph Friedman in 1937.

Answer (score 0):

It's called a:

> [flexi-straw](https://www.google.com/search?q=flexi-straw&rlz=1C1GGLS_en-GBGB359GB359&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi6m9_J66HVAhVKGhQKHYTeBS4QsAQIxgE&biw=1280&bih=687)

(from flexible)

Answer (score 0):

May also be called "[bendable straws](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004HX8F26)"

[image]